# erroneous results when trying to read value from database using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am trying to query from database through python using cx_oracle and sqlalchemy
I find the cx_oracle seems to give correct results while sql_alchemy gives erroneous results

Actual value in database: 3,360,000,000
When using sqlalchemy : -934,967,296
when using cx_oracle: 3,360,000,000

I want to use sqlalachemy. can u please tell me what is wrong with my code. I think it could be an overflow error.

Code cx_oracle

```
class DatabaseConnection:
    def __init__(self, ip, port, SID, user_name, password):
        self.ip = ip  # ip address of the host
        self.port = port  # port of the host
        self.SID = SID  # SID
        self.user_name = user_name  # user name of the database
        self.password = password  # password of the database

    # function to connect to the database
    def connect(self):
        dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(self.ip, self.port, self.SID)
        db = cx_Oracle.connect(self.user_name, self.password, dsn_tns)
        return db

    database = DatabaseConnection(host, port, SID, user_name, password)
    db = database.connect()
    sql_bp = "some sql query"
    bp1 = pd.read_sql(sql_bp, db)
```

code sqlalchemy:

```
    engine_query = 

    "oracle+cx_oracle://"+user_name+":"+password+"@"+host+":"+port+"/"+SID
    engine = create_engine(engine_query)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    bp = pd.read_sql(sql_bp, engine)
```

Comment: Looks like integer overflow

Comment: How to make sure that the integer flow doesn't happen ?